# Decoding failed and unknown chip XID 641 errors when trying to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, grub2, 20.04, windows-10

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 with Windows 10 but when I try to boot off my live USB I get the errors:

1. Initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed
2. r8169 0000:03:00.0: unknown chip XID 641

How can I fix these errors?

Secure boot and fast boot are currently disabled and my system is:

MSI Z490 Gaming Edge Wifi

Intel i7 10700K

EVGA Geforce RTX 2060 super

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same problem. Is there a ubuntu version that immediately solves the problem?

Comment: For me there was a problem with the Nouveau graphics driver which Ubuntu uses by default. The most recent version of Ubuntu 20.04 has a safe graphics mode from the grub screen which got me in and then you can install the Nvidia driver. I also needed to install WiFi and Ethernet drivers. You can see if you need to do this with `lshw -C network` and if it says `UNCLAIMED` then you need to install them.

Comment: I found that there was no issue installing 20.10.

Answer (score 2):

This is a result of not having a driver for the network card.  Fortunately, as of the time of this posting, Realtek appears to have great support when it comes to providing drivers for their users. You can go

https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/rtl8169sc-l-software

[image]

Once you have the file, extract it to a directory on your machine and follow the directions in the `readme` file.  They will look something like this

```
# bunzip2 r8169-6.028.02.tar.bz2  (Note version numbers may change)
# tar xvf r8169-6.028.02.tar
# cd r8169-6.028.02
# make clean modules    (as root or with sudo)
# make install
# depmod -a
# modprobe r8169
```

While not done on the Live CD version, I was able to successfully build (all steps prior to `make install`) the driver using Ubuntu 20.04. A similar process worked easily for the r8125 which comes with the MSI Z490 Unify motherboard. In that case there is a shell script they have you run called `autorun.sh`.  A reboot was not required for it to start working.

Comment: For me this doesn't seem to work on 20.04, I get the following error: 
```INSTALL /mnt/Data/Distrib/r8169-6.029.00/src/r8169.ko
At main.c:160:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: ../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69```
I tried researching this, didn't find much info so far... I guess one option is to wait for 22.04

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem while installing ubuntu 20.04 in my PC with i7 11700. The problem is with the kernel of ubuntu 20.04 which later on cannot able to detect the 750D graphics of Intel. This problem can be overcomed by either installing 21.04 which has 5.12 version of kernel or upgrading the 20.04 kernel to the newly 5.13.

Answer (score 0):

Use the search engine of your choice to look for the r8169 error message you got, and you'll find the answer. RTL8125B support comes with kernel 5.9 only.

Comment: It may not be supported directly in the kernel but the card manufacture produces drivers that are available for download.

Comment: My problem is, how to install a driver without installing the ubuntu system...

Comment: When you use the search engine of your choice to search for an error message and you end up on a page asking you to do what you just did. People realise technical search results usually end up directing to stackoverflow right?

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.10 with kernel 5.8 I would get the message on "Unkown chip" but it did show up in lspci. Now, after Ubuntu upgrade, I am at kernel 5.11 and the NIC no longer shows up in lspci, even! So if anything.. newer kernels have LESS support for it.