# shim-signed breaks dkms

Tags: 16.04, dkms

I'm trying to install the dkms package on Ubuntu 16.04.
I cannot have access to Internet because Ubuntu does not detect the ethernet adapter (Realtek)
Googling the problem, it seems I have to install the r8168 driver and I downloaded with another PC the r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb file and I tried to install it. Unfortunately it depends on *dkms* which is not installed.

Thus, I manually downloaded the dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb and I run the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11_all.deb
```

but I have a problem with shim-signed, which I am not familiar with.

```
shim-signed (1.33.1~16.04.5+15+1533136590.3beb971-0ubuntu1) breaks dkms (<< 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.6) and is installed
```

I followed Method 2 of this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS to disable Secure Boot in shim-signed, but honestly I don't even know if it makes sense (and it did not solve the problem)...

Does anyone know how to install dkms without internet connection?

**Update 1**

I deleted the 16.04 and I succesfully installed Ubuntu 20.04.
However, it only detects the wi-fi adapter, not the ethernet one.

The ethernet adapter should be: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

```
lspci -v:
Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer RTS5260 PCI Express Card Reader
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 151
    Memory at a2100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

```
lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2; ifconfig
Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:3000] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer Device [1558:7714]
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

```
lshw -c network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:48:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2200000-a220ffff memory:a2210000-a2213fff
```

```
uname -r
5.8.0-44-generic
```

```
cat: /etc/network/interfaces: No such file or directory
```

**Update 2**

I added to the blacklist the r8169 driver. I added the following parameters to the "kernel command" during the booting (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_module#Blacklisting):

```
module_blacklist=r8169
```

Then, I manually uploaded the r8168 with:

```
modprobe r8168
```

However, it seems it does not work:

```
dmesg

[  288.556472] r8168: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

**Update 3**

Following the first answer of @heynnema, I run

```
sudo apt install dkms r8168-dkms
```

but I got these errors:

```
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/r8168-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.048.00/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package r8168-dkms (--configure):
 installed r8168-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 r8168-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the make.log file:

```
less /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.048.00/build/make.log

DKMS make.log for r8168-8.048.00 for kernel 5.8.0-44-generic (x86_64)
dom 7 mar 2021, 17:58:28, CET
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-44-generic'

  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.

make: *** [Makefile:746: include/config/auto.conf] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-44-generic'
```

**Update 4**

From [v5.9.16](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.16/) I installed the following packages running

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

- linux-headers-5.9.16-050916_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_all.deb
- linux-headers-5.9.16-050916-generic_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_amd64.deb
- linux-image-unsigned-5.9.16-050916-generic_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_amd64.deb
- linux-modules-5.9.16-050916-generic_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_amd64.deb

but I got the following error:

```
Setting up linux-headers-5.9.16-050916-generic (5.9.16-050916.202012211331) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.9.16-050916-generic

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j20 KERNELRELEASE=5.9.16-050916-generic -C /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.048.00/build.....
Signing module:
 - /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.048.00/5.9.16-050916-generic/x86_64/module/r8168.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

r8168.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

Warning: Unable to find an initial ram disk that I know how to handle.
Will not try to make an initrd.

DKMS: install completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j20 KERNELRELEASE=5.9.16-050916-generic KVERSION=5.9.16-050916-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rts_pstor: 1.11 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.9.16-050916-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rts_pstor/1.11/build/make.log for more information.
   ...done.
```

The installation is however completed but when I try to boot the new kernel, it prints some errors without completing the booting process (black screen).

**Update 5**

```
dkms status

r8168, 8.048.00, 5.8.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168, 8.048.00, 5.8.0-45-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
r8168, 8.048.00, 5.9.16-050916-generic, x86_64: installed
rts_pstor, 1.11: added
```

```
cat /var/lib/dkms/rts_pstor/1.11/build/make.log 

DKMS make.log for rts_pstor-1.11 for kernel 5.9.16-050916-generic (x86_64)
sab 20 mar 2021, 11:35:44, CET
sed "s/RTSX_MK_TIME/`date +%y.%m.%d.%H.%M`/" timestamp.in > timestamp.h
cp -f ./define.release ./define.h
make -C /lib/modules/5.9.16-050916-generic/build/ SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/rts_pstor/1.11/build modules
make[1]: warning: jobserver unavailable: using -j1.  Add '+' to parent make rule.
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.16-050916-generic'
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:9: scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
make[2]: *** [Makefile:606: syncconfig] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:711: include/config/auto.conf.cmd] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.9.16-050916-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:39: default] Error 2
```

**Update 6**

```
sudo lshw -C network

  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:47:00.0
       logical name: wlp71s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 5c:80:b6:8f:c3:4d
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-48-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode ip=192.168.178.66 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:16 memory:a2300000-a2303fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:48:00.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2200000-a220ffff memory:a2210000-a2213fff
```

Comment: Why are you using 16.04? Server or Desktop installation? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and I'll take a look. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I ve updated the question, thanks! :)

Comment: @heynnema it is Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

Comment: Show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`.

Comment: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`
`# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager`

Comment: @heynnema I've updated the question

Comment: Please see my initial answer. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `module_blacklist=r8169` from /etc/default/grub, and then `sudo update-grub`. <strike>If the r8168-dkms module is installed, the proper place to blacklist the r8169, if required, would be in /etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf. But don't do that yet</strike>.

The r8169 kernel module **is required** to drive your ethernet card...

```
Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:3000] (rev 06)
```

<strike>Assuming that you have wireless connectivity, do this...</strike>

`dkms status`

If only r8168-dkms shows up, then do this...

`sudo rm -i /var/crash/r8168-dkms.0.crash`

`sudo apt purge r8168-dkms dkms`

`sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.8.0-44-generic`

`sudo apt install build-essential dkms r8168-dkms`

`reboot`

**Update #1:**

For kernel 5.9.16... [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.16/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.16/). Download the 4 files, but skip the low-latency files, install, and report back.

**Update #2:**

Boot to the 5.8.0-45-generic kernel.

`sudo apt purge`  the 5.9.16-050916-generic kernel... (easiest to install `gdebi` and use that to uninstall the following .deb files...)

```
linux-headers-5.9.16-050916_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_all.deb
linux-headers-5.9.16-050916-generic_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_amd64.deb
linux-image-unsigned-5.9.16-050916-generic_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_amd64.deb
linux-modules-5.9.16-050916-generic_5.9.16-050916.202012211331_amd64.deb
```

`sudo dkms remove r8168/8.048.00 --all` # remove r8168 from all kernels

`sudo apt purge r8168-dkms` # remove the r8168 driver

Remove `module_blacklist=r8169` from /etc/default/grub (if it's still there)

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot` # reboot the computer

If required for card reader...

- `sudo dkms build rts_pstor/1.11` # build the card reader kernel module
- `sudo dkms install rts_pstor/1.11` # install the card reader kernel module
- `dkms status` # confirm the card reader module shows as installed

Otherwise...

- `sudo dkms remove rts_pstor/1.11 --all`

Comment: The first steps went fine, however `sudo apt install dkms r8168-dkms` reports an error, see the updated question

Comment: @F.DePa I've updated my answer. Remember to remove the blacklisting.

Comment: All the commands went right but they did not solve the problem. The ouput of `dmesg` is `r8169 0000:48:00.0: unknown chip XID 641`. It might be [link] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269783/decoding-failed-and-unknown-chip-xid-641-errors-when-trying-to-dual-boot-ubuntu) that the adapter is only supported from kernel >= 5.9 (mine is 5.8.0-44-generic)

Comment: @F.DePa Here's the link for kernel 5.9.16... https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.9.16/ download the 4 files, but skip the low-latency files, and give that a try, and report back.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have access to that computer right now. I will try at the end of the week.

Comment: @F.DePa Status please...

Comment: I've updated my question

Comment: @F.DePa Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `ls -al /boot` and `cat /var/lib/dkms/rts_pstor/1.11/build/make.log`

Comment: @F.DePa Status please...

Comment: Please, see the updated question

Comment: @F.DePa I've updated my answer.

Comment: I followed your update but I still cannot detect the network Ethernet adapter

Comment: @F.DePa Edit your question and show me the current status of `grep -i r816 /etc/default/grub` and `grep -i r816 /etc/modprobe.d/*.conf` and `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: @F.DePa And `grep -i r816 /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: I updated my question. Unfortunately, only the command `sudo lshw -C network` got an output.

Comment: @F.DePa Good. Do `sudo modprobe r8169` and see if the ethernet interface starts to work.